# Is there any AST-level analysis/instrumentation tool for Rust?

Tags: rust, static-analysis

I have a need to analyze Rust source code globally (the analyzer needs to look at the entire program) and rewrite the code accordingly. Basically, I have something like LLVM passes in my mind, but here I need the information of Rust source code. I try to find an existing framework for this task but the only one I found (https://github.com/da-x/instru) has not been maintained for long. Also, I notice there is a so-called "compiler plugin" in `rustc` but seems the `rustc` team has also stopped the support of it.

So I post this to see if anyone has any idea of the common practice in Rust for this kind of analysis/instrumentation task?

Comment: "Compiler plugins" were superseded by [procedural macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html) which are given the tokens of some Rust syntactical item which can then be transformed. However, it is only a local mechanism though (you have to annotate or wrap what you want to transform) so if you want a "global" tool you'd need to look for external tools that could possibly be used in a build script. What kind of analysis/instrumentation are you doing?

Comment: @kmdreko I want to determine if a variable is used in unsafe and rewrite its occurrence accordingly. Also I might want to rewrite some variable names based on information somewhere else in the program (maybe very far from where it is).

Comment: @DizzyZeratul To do that you need name resolution, and macro expansion, meaning you can't work on the AST but on the HIR. But going from the HIR to source code back is not easily doable, and not always even possible. rustc was certainly not written with that as a goal in mind. You may want to use the rust-analyzer AST and HIR, as it was designed with this goal in mind, although it is still not always possible to go from macro-expanded code to source code.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Thanks for the tips! In my case, I might be able to first let `rustc` outputs HIR, do my stuff on the HIR, then continue the compilation. But it seems like the `rustc` cannot take HIR as input, is that right?

Comment: @DizzyZeratul Yes. You will need to patch rustc.